# Proving that $\exp(-x^2-y^2)$ is a strictly quasi-concave function

Tags: economics

Prove that
$$f(x,y)=\exp(-x^2-y^2)$$ is a strictly quasi-concave function, that is,$\forall (x_i,y_i)\in \Re^2, (x_i,y_i)\neq (x_j,y_j), \lambda\in(0,1)$,
$$f(\lambda x_1+(1-\lambda) x_2,\lambda y_1+(1-\lambda) y_2)>\min[f(x_1,y_1),f(x_2,y_2)].$$

I'm trying to use triangle inequality but so far without success. Perhaps some insight will be useful.

Answer (score 1):

The logarithm is a strictly increasing monotonic function, so if $a>b$ then $\log a>\log b$ and vice-versa. Take logarithms then
$$
\log (e^{-x^2-y^2})=-2(\log x+\log y)
$$
Using just one dimension, suppose that the maximum is at $x_1$ then
$$
\log \exp -(\lambda x_1+(1-\lambda)x_2)^2=
-2(\lambda x_1+(1-\lambda)x_2)\\
>-2x_1
$$
by the usual inequalities.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is to observe a function $f$ is (strictly) quasi-concave if and only if all the upper contours set $\{x: f(x)\ge \alpha\}$ are (strictly) convex.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).